# GAE: how to add new data in a memcache var

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

I'm blocked right now.

The problem is this: I have my "view" of a list of books stored in memcache. If I add a new book, I want to add the new book to the memcache variable that stores the list of books. Same for update and delete.

You can say: "you can flush the key and gather all data again". But due to eventual consistency, when I add and immediately query the new data, the new data isn't still there.

You can say: "use ancestors to avoid eventual consistency". The books are the root entities, and for performance, it's not a good idea to use ancestors at this level.

So, the idea is to read from datastore the less as possible, and have memcache syncronized.

Now my code, that doesn't work:

```
class Book(ndb.Model):
    """ A Book """
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    author = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

    @classmethod
    def getAll(cls):
        key = 'books'
        books = memcache.get(key)
        if books is None:
            books = list(Book.query().order(Book.title).fetch(100))
            if not memcache.set(key, books):
                logging.error('Memcache set failed for key %s.', key)
        else:
            logging.info('Memcache hit for key %s.', key)
        return books

    @classmethod
    def addMemcache(cls, newdata):
        mylist = memcache.get('books')
        if mylist:
            mylist.insert(0, newdata)
            if not memcache.set('books', mylist):
                logging.error('Memcache set failed for key books.')

    # This saves the data comming from the form
    @classmethod
    def save(cls, **kwargs):
        book = Book(title=kwargs['title'],
                    author=kwargs['author']
               )
        # Save
        book.put()
        # Add to memcache for this key
        logging.info('Adding to Memcache for key books.')
        cls.addMemcache([book.title, book.author])
        return book
```

For now I'm simply inserting at start of the list.
The problem with my code is that when I ADD to memcache, I'm missing some kind of property because the jinja template says "UndefinedError: 'list object' has no attribute 'title'", when is trying to represent this line:

```
<td>{{ line.title[:40]|escape }}</td>
```

Which is obvious, because is a list, not an object with properties. But why it works when I convert the object in a list in the function getAll(), making books = list(the_query)?

My other problems will be how to modify an especific book (in this case I can flush de memcache and read again, because there is not eventual consistency problem I think) and how to delete (how to identify a unique element in the list if 2 books have the same name).

Any suggestion? Or must I change my solution to the problem of have memcache syncronized?

Comment: Has nothing to do with the answer.. but in Python dontUseCamelCase for function but lower_case_underscores.. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Lipis. I find lower_case style ugly, but if it is a convention, I will change it.

Comment: it_is_much_easier_to_read_if_think_about_it compareToTheCamelCaseThingThatIsUnreadable :) http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names

Comment: He, he, I was reading http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles meanwhile. But... for me is the same to read lower_case_names than CamelCaseNames. I'm used to CamelCase and I read it very easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing two different things when setting your memcache values. In `getAll`, on a cache miss you do `memcache.set(key, books)` where `books` is a list of Book instances. But in `addMemcache` (called by `save)` you insert a *list of lists*, where the inner list is the title and author of the book. So as you've noted, when you get the values from the cache, they are a mixture of instances and lists.

Seems like the line in save should just be:

```
cls.addMemcache(book)
```

so that you consistently set Book instances to the cache.

(Also note that I'd probably make `addMemcache` a normal instance method rather than a classmethod, that adds `self` to the memcache list. And in save it would be better to instantiate `cls` rather than explicitly invoking `Book`, in case you ever subclass.)

Comment: Perfect @DanielRoseman, works like a charm. I usually forget the power that Python have and begin to do complicated things when with Python all is more easy!! Thank you also for your notes, it were very clever. Any suggestion for update? Maybe just delete and add it again? For delete I assume that I need to search the title and remove it.

Comment: I got the right solution, thanks. Will post it in a few hours (I can't autorespond my self until 8 hours, not enought reputation).

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @DanielRoseman I got the final solution for the problem.

I just want to leave here the complete solution for other interested "stackers". It includes the add, edit and delete elements to memcache, that are working now.

```
# These classes define the data objects to store in AppEngine's data store.
class Book(ndb.Model):
    """ A Book """
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    author = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    deleted = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False)

    MEMCACHE_TIMEOUT = 0

    # Key to use in memcache for the list of all books
    @staticmethod
    def book_memkey(key='book_list'):
        return str(key)

    # Search all
    @classmethod
    def get_all(cls):
        key = cls.book_memkey()
        books = memcache.get(key)
        if books is None:
            books = list(Book.query().order(Book.title).fetch(100))
            if not memcache.set(key, books, cls.MEMCACHE_TIMEOUT):
                logging.error('Memcache set failed for key %s.', key)
        else:
            logging.info('Memcache hit for key %s.', key)
        return books

    # Save a Book and return it
    @classmethod
    def save(cls, **kwargs):
        book = cls(title=kwargs['title'],
                   author=kwargs['author']
                  )
        book.put()
        # Modify memcache for this key
        book.add_to_memcache()
        return book

    # ------------------------
    # Methods for the instance
    # ------------------------

    # Add a new element to memcache
    def add_to_memcache(self):
        data = memcache.get(self.book_memkey())
        if data:
            logging.info('Adding to Memcache for key %s.', self.book_memkey())
            data.insert(0, self)
            if not memcache.set(self.book_memkey(), data, self.MEMCACHE_TIMEOUT):
                logging.error('Memcache set failed for key %s.', self.book_memkey())

    # Remove an element from memcache
    def del_from_memcache(self):
        data = memcache.get(self.book_memkey())
        if data:
            logging.info('Removing from Memcache for key %s.', self.book_memkey())
            try:
                # Search the object in the list
                element = filter(lambda idx: idx.key == self.key, data)[0]
            except IndexError:
                pass
            else:
                logging.info('Removing element %s.', element)
                data.remove(element)
                if not memcache.set(self.book_memkey(), data, self.MEMCACHE_TIMEOUT):
                    logging.error('Memcache set failed for key %s.', self.book_memkey())

    # Update an element on memcache
    def update_memcache(self):
        data = memcache.get(self.book_memkey())
        if data:
            logging.info('Updating Memcache for key %s.', self.book_memkey())
            try:
                # Search the object in the list
                element = filter(lambda idx: idx.key == self.key, data)[0]
            except IndexError:
                pass
            else:
                logging.info('Updating element %s.', element)
                data[data.index(element)] = self
                if not memcache.set(self.book_memkey(), data, self.MEMCACHE_TIMEOUT):
                    logging.error('Memcache set failed for key %s.', self.book_memkey())

    # Update a chapter
    def update(self, **kwargs):
        if 'title' in kwargs:
            self.title = kwargs['title']
        if 'author' in kwargs:
            self.author = kwargs['author']
        # Save
        self.put()
        self.update_memcache()

    # Delete de book (mark as deleted). Optionally you can assign Value=False to undelete
    def virtual_delete(self, value=True):
        self.deleted = value
        if value:
            self.del_from_memcache()
        else:
            self.add_to_memcache()
        self.put()
```